# The resource cannot be found in asp.net for login

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a **HomeController** which has **Login** and **Dashboard** actions defined in it. But, when I am requesting the url **/Home/Dashboard** through Login action a server error(HTTP 404) is showing up. I have defined views for both Login and Dashboard also. My HomeController is like this.

```
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
    public ActionResult Login()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Login(UserProfile objUser)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            using(DB_Entities db = new DB_Entities())
            {
                var obj = db.UserProfiles.Where(a => a.UserName.Equals(objUser.UserName) && a.Password.Equals(objUser.Password)).FirstOrDefault();

                if (obj != null)
                {
                    Session["UserID"] = obj.UserId.ToString();
                    Session["UserName"] = obj.UserName.ToString();
                    return RedirectToAction("Dashboard");
                }
                else
                {
                    ViewBag.Message = "Invalid Username or Password";
                }
            }
        }

        return View(objUser);
    }

    public ActionResult Dashboad()
    {
        if (Session["UserID"] != null)
        {
            return View();
        }
        else
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Login");
        }
    }
}
```

Login action is working correctly.

Comment: Dashboad != Dashboa**r**d

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct the typo in the Action name:

```
public ActionResult Dashboard()
```

Answer (score 1):

Error(HTTP 404) is a typical Resource no found error. So, please check the dashboard action name.

Please update the action "public ActionResult Dashboad()" to "public ActionResult Dashboard()", You will fix the issues.

Answer (score 0):

There was a typo in Dashboard definition and redirect.